# Antlr4 create more meaningful/consistent type name

Tags: java, antlr4

By default the `token.getType()` method returns an `int`, and is pretty useless to code based upon, without loading and parsing the `*.tokens` file that is generated.

How do ANTLR users usually go about making consistent use of the token types? What I mean by consistent is that if you change the grammar, the token numbers are very likely to change.

Do you typically create a `Utility` class that loads the `*.tokens` file and parses it?

My sample `Search.tokens` file:

```
LOCATION=8
TIME=5
AGE=3
WS=1
COMPARATIVE=9
GENDER=4
PHRASE=2
```

A sample token stream:

```
(token.getType(), token.getText())
9 [MegaBlocks vs Legos], -1 [<EOF>]
```

Currently I'm doing something like:

```
public class TokenMapper {

    private HashMap<Integer, String> tokens;

    public TokenMapper(String file) {
        tokens = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        parse(file);
    }

    private void parse(String file) {
        // trivial code that maps the Integer typeId to the String name
    }

    public Integer type(String type) {
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : tokens.entrySet()) {
            if(entry.getValue().equals(type)) {
                return entry.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String type(Integer type) {
        return tokens.get(type);
    }   

}
```

Then I can always refer to my tokens by names such as `LOCATION` or `GENDER` and don't have to worry about the `Integer` values that tend to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate your lexer and/or parser, the generated class will contain constants for each token type declared in the grammar as well as the ones imported via a tokens file.

For example, if you have the following grammar:

```
lexer grammar SearchLexer;

options { tokenVocab = Search; }

...
```

Then the generated `SearchLexer.java` class will contain constants (`public static final int`) for `LOCATION` and `GENDER` because they were imported due to the `tokenVocab` option.